# Nine-digit telephone numbers with one digit being removed to form a eight-digit number

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

How many nine-digit numbers exist such that when a single digit is crossed out, a given telephone number, comprising eight digits is obtained ?

---

My attempt:-

Total 9 digit numbers that can be formed = $9*10^8$

From these set of numbers, those having 0 at the 2nd place should be removed because if we remove the first digit , then it would become a 7-digit number

Hence my answer turns out to be $9*10^8$-$9*10^7$=$81*10^7$

My answer isnt remotely close to the official answer which is 89, have I misinterpreted the question, or is the answer dubious ?

Comment: I think the answer of 89 is only valid if the given 8-digit telephone number does not have any repeated adjacent digits. For example, if the telephone number was 33333333 then there are only 82 nine-digit strings that contain it (or 81 if no leading zero is allowed).

Comment: Good point, @JaapScherphuis.

Comment: How do we know the telephone number ? I am not able to get how the answer is so small whereas I have it in the range of $10^7$

Comment: @VasuGupta The question says you are given it. If you are given a specific 8-digit phone number (with no repeated digits), how many 9-digit strings contain it?